# How to resize/compress a camera image or gallery image in android before upload to server?

Tags: android, image-resizing

I have to upload image which may be choose from gallery or take by camera. I have done this successfully. But problem is , some time image size is 1MB. So it takes more time to upload to server. I need to resize this image before upload. How to do this?

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    AlertDialog alertDialog1;

    if( requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ){
        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(destination);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 10;
            imagePath = destination.getAbsolutePath();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            //img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            int nh = (int) ( bmp.getHeight() * (512.0 / bmp.getWidth()) );
            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 512, nh, true);
            img.setImageBitmap(scaled);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // AlertDialog alertDialog1;
            alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
            alertDialog1.setTitle("Message");
            alertDialog1.setMessage("bala \t "+e.toString());
            alertDialog1.show();
        }

    }else if (requestCode == 1) {
        try {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagePath =  getPath(selectedImageUri);
            destination = new File(imagePath);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(destination);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 10;
            imagePath = destination.getAbsolutePath();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            //int nh = (int) ( bmp.getHeight() * (512.0 / bmp.getWidth()) );
           // Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 512, nh, true);
            img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            //img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // AlertDialog alertDialog1;
            alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
            alertDialog1.setTitle("Message");
            alertDialog1.setMessage("sang\t"+e.toString());
            alertDialog1.show();
        }
    }
    else{

    }
}
```

Now, how to resize the image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize image taken from gallery or camera, before being uploaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813604/resize-image-taken-from-gallery-or-camera-before-being-uploaded)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android

Answer (score 3):

1. To resize image you can use the following function

   `Bitmap yourBitmap;
   Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);`
2. To compress the image

   `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(miFoto)
   ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);
   InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
   ContentBody foto = new InputStreamBody(in, "image/jpeg", "filename");`

Comment: can u provide full coding? where to use this code in my coding?

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout this code it works same as you wanted [WhatsApp Like Image Compression](https://gist.github.com/vipulasri/0cd97d012934531f1266). This code has been modified according to my usage.
Using this code will provide you :

- Low Size Images around **100kb** without playing with image quality.
- High pixel images will be scaled down to *maxWidth* and *maxHeight* without loosing its original quality.

Original Article : [Loading images Super-Fast like WhatsApp](http://abdelhady.net/2015/03/28/android-loading-images-super-fast-like-whatsapp-part-2/)

Demo  :

[Original Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7SVudPeYXS7WGM2X2xsWEs0Tkk/view?usp=sharing) :   Size - 3.84Mb Dimensions - 3120*4160

[Compressed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wifGu.jpg) : Size - 157Kb  Dimensions - 960*1280

Answer (score 1):

you need to compress the image because Re-scaling bitmap reduce the quality of image. you can try this function for compress your image. just pass this funtion from where you upload your image in your activity.

```
/ Funtion for compress image
    public String compressImage(String imageUri) {

        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

        float maxHeight = 816.0f;
        float maxWidth = 612.0f;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {               imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);               actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;             } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return filename;

    }


    public String getFilename() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyFolder/Images");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        return uriSting;

    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height/ (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;      }       final float totalPixels = width * height;       final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;       while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    //
    private void previewMedia(boolean isImage) {


        // Checking whether captured media is image or video
        if (isImage) {
            photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // vidPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();


            // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 2;


            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;


            photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

compress bitmap like

```
bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 160, 160, true);
```

Comment: it does not worked . original image size is 867kb and scaled image also same

Answer (score 0):

can use:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath());
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream); //compress to 50% of original image quality
byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
```